# How to convert a list of strings into a dictionary with keys and values matching

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this list in a file:
Alabama
4802982
9
Alaska
721523
3
Arizona
6412700
11
Arkansas
2926229
6
California
37341989
55
Colorado
5044930
9

(Except it continues for every state) I need to create a dictionary with the state names as keys and both the population and electoral votes(first and second numbers) as a list of values.

This is my function so far:

```
def make_elector_dictionary(file):
    dic = {}
    try:
        infile = open(file,'r')
    except IOError:
        print('file not found')
    else:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            dic[line] = ()
        print(dic)
```

Comment: Go have a look at the `split` method of the string object. That will help.

Comment: Got it working with for i in range(0,len(wordlist)-2,3):
            dic[wordlist[i]] = (wordlist[i+1],wordlist[i+2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = "Alabama 4802982 9 Alaska 721523 3 Arizona 6412700 11 Arkansas 2926229 6 California 37341989 55 Colorado 5044930 9"
l = s.split()
dictionaryYouWant = {l[index]: [l[index+1], l[index+2]] for index in range(0, len(l), 3)}
```

`split` the string by space to split it into words, then loop through every three, making an item first one : list of the last two with a dictionary comprehension.

This gives:

```
{'Alabama': ['4802982', '9'], 'Alaska': ['721523', '3'], 'Arizona': ['6412700', '11'], 'Arkansas': ['2926229', '6'], 'California': ['37341989', '55'], 'Colorado': ['5044930', '9']}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you roughly what you want:

```
def make_elector_dictionary(file):

    # Open and read the entire file
    try:
        with open(file,'r') as infile:
            raw_data = infile.read()
    except IOError:
        print('file not found')
        return

    # Split the text into an array, using a space as the separator between array elements
    raw_data = raw_data.split(' ')

    # Rearrange the data into a dictionary of dictionaries
    processed_data = {raw_data[i]: {'pop': int(raw_data[i+1]), 'electoral_votes': int(raw_data[i+2])}
                  for i in range(0, len(raw_data), 3) }

    return processed_data

print(make_elector_dictionary('data.txt'))
```

This gives:

```html
{'Arizona': {'pop': 6412700, 'electoral_votes': 11}, 'Arkansas': {'pop': 2926229, 'electoral_votes': 6}, 'California': {'pop': 37341989, 'electoral_votes': 55}, 'Colorado': {'pop': 5044930, 'electoral_votes': 9}, 'Alabama': {'pop': 4802982, 'electoral_votes': 9}, 'Alaska': {'pop': 721523, 'electoral_votes': 3}}
```

Or you can use

```
processed_data = {raw_data[i]: [int(raw_data[i+1]), int(raw_data[i+2])]
                  for i in range(0, len(raw_data), 3) }
```

if you want the dictionary values to be arrays rather than dictionaries. Whether this approach works is a bit dependent on the details of your data file. For instance, if "New Hampshire" is written in your datafile with a space between "New" and "Hampshire", then "New" will be interpreted by the function as the state name, and you'll get a ValueError when you try to pass "Hampshire" to int as the population. In this case, you'd have to resort to some more sophisticated parsing to get this to work--regular expressions are probably the best option. You could do:

```
    processed_data = {match[1]: [match[2], match[3]]
                  for match in re.findall(r'(\W|^)([a-zA-z ]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)', raw_data)}
```

Remember to `import re`. This is probably the most robust approach. It will handle the New Hampshire-type case and, in the form above, is not dependent on the type of whitespace that separates the data elements.